# Python API to make phone call and play audio file

Tags: python, api, python-3.x, audio

I am writing a program in Python and part of the program requires the user to listen to an audio file which is dynamically generated in the code.

Does anyone know of a service (free or paid) that call make a phone call and then play said audio file. If not, does anyone know of an alternative where I would be able to stream an audio clip to a smartphone (perhaps an android app that connects to the python)?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checkout Twilio.com or Plivo. They offers the api you are looking for

https://www.twilio.com/

https://www.plivo.com/